# What term can I use for a function applied to each element of a sequence, while aware of its index?

Tags: c++, foreach, functional-programming, terminology, functor

This is a question about terminology, or concepts (not C++ concepts).

If I write

```
std::for_each(my_start, my_end, f);
```

You would say I applied the function, or functor, or function object `f` to each element in the range; and f's signature is either

```
void f(const decltype(*my_start)& x);
```

or it has an operator

```
void operator()(const decltype(*my_start)& x);
```

Now, suppose I do the same thing, but the function gets not just a reference to the element of the range, but also its index: For *my_start it gets 0, then 1 etc. Now the signatures are

```
void f(size_t i, const decltype(*my_start)& x);
void operator()(size_t i, const decltype(*my_start)& x);
```

(if you don't like `size_t` then pretend it's `int`).

So, the question is: Is there a term for these kinds of functors/functions? Or for this operation of applying such a function/functor/function object to a range of elements?

Comment: enumerate? Compare with Python's [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function which yields `(idx, element)` for each element of the original sequence.

Answer (score -1):

So, based on @Andrew's comment, let's call this operation an **enumerated foreach**, and if the original f was a unary function, we can call the enumerated variant an **enumerated unary function**, and its first argument could be the **enumerator**.